# websocket doesn't get connected

Tags: websocket, ubuntu-12.04

I could connect websocket to the server on my local machine. But when i uploaded the file to a remote ubuntu server, it doesn't work any more.

Server side code(server.php):

```
$master = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($master, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_bind($master, "127.0.0.1", 80);
socket_listen($master, 20);
```

client side code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var host = "ws://127.0.0.1:80/server.php";
socket = new WebSocket(host);
</script>
```

I open the client page from chrome canary version 24, server side didn't get any accepted socket.

I changed the host to "ws://xx.xx.xx.xx:80/server.php" to the real IP address of the server, doesn't work. Also changed the server side socket_bind($master, "127.0.0.1", 80) to real ip, no luck either.

Any one can help me?

Thanks,

Jasmine

Comment: What error messages do you see?

Answer (score 0):

My friend, when you write your server. You need to keep it running as a service or just keep it running.
In the case of a php server, you need to run that file from the PHP Cli (php yourfile.php), not from the browser (You can, setting the timeout to 0, but if you close the browser, your server stops working).
I really don't recommend a socket server over PHP. Read more about socket servers with C++ (QT, Berkeley), or Java Socket Servers.

When we are talking about HTML5 Websockets Server, it's different from programming a 'normal' socket server (There are a lot of libraries for PHP that can help you programming a HTML5 Websocket server)

https://github.com/Flynsarmy/PHPWebSocket-Chat

In that link, you can find an example of a chat. There is a file called class.PHPWebSocket.php, include it in your server.php and use that library for the creation of the HTML5 Websocket Server. See the examples, read how it works and how to use the class.PHPWebSocket.php (Take a look at the server.php file inside the examples).

Run the server when you finish it.

Then do:

```
// ...
var host = "ws://IP.OF.THE.SERVER:port";
socket = new WebSocket(host);
// ...
```

Read more about socket servers, HTML5 Websockets, and take a look at that class.PHPWebSocket.php utility.
Good Luck My Friend.

Comment: Also, check the IP Address of the server, do a ping to the server, and take a look at that IP:Port/**SERVER.PHP**

Comment: thanks for your help. The server code i am useing is just copy from phpwebsocket code. And I do keep server side running there by php server.php. The problem is $client = socket_accept($master); this line doesn't get any socket in. It works on my local computer though.

Comment: Check the connection, maybe the client is not connecting with the server, do the: socket.onclose and socket.onerror in your javascript, and take a look of what is happening there.

Comment: Oh, and remember "ip:port/file.php" is a path to that file.php, if you are using "ws://xx.xx.xx.xx:80/server.php" he is going to search server.php, so, try removing "/server.php", or moving that server.php in your server to the root path.
Do you have an apache running on that server?

Comment: Actually my client code likes this: var host = "ws://72.44.39.251:2012/server.php";
 try { 
  socket = new WebSocket(host);
  log('WebSocket - status ' + socket.readyState);
  
  socket.onopen    = function(msg){ log("Welcome - status " + this.readyState + msg); };
  socket.onclose   = function(msg){ log("Disconnected - status " + this.readyState + msg.type + msg.data); };

  socket.onerror = function(msg){ log("Error - status " + this.readyState + msg.type + msg.data); };
 }
 catch (e) {
  log(e);
 } screen looks like this: WebSocket - status 0
Disconnected - status 3 close undefined

Comment: Your client looks good, Ok, tell me more about your server (If you have an apache, where you have your server.php, if the ping over the server is not failing...)

Comment: Ps, apache running on that server. Removed /server.php, still doesn't work. server.php is in the root directory of DocumentRoot directory.

Comment: Apache normally runs over the port 80 and you are runnign the server over the port 80, try this:
Configure your server for run under the IP, and a different Port (Idk.... 44445, be sure that the new port is not used).
On the variable host, change the value to: "ws://IP:NewPort".

How do you have your server.php configured?

Comment: changed to port 2012, doesn't work. Server is running on a amazon Elastic Compute Cloud Server, Opt sys is ubuntu. Port 2012 is opened there too. Not sure whether i need to install any package for websocket for php or apache.

Comment: Hmm, I'm doing a ping to 72.44.39.251, it seems that it's failing... It's most like a connections issues...

Comment: yup, ping using ICMP protocal, it is not enalbed on my ubuntu server. But I opened my TCP port 2012.

Comment: oops, pasted server.php code in the first answer. suppose to be in origin post. anyway.

Comment: Just a question. Do you have any connection errors? The client is connecting with the server?
It seems to be working good, I already tested the client and the server. Maybe, they are connection issues, and they are not problems with the server or client.
Oh! And on the server.php keep the address as 127.0.0.1, and on the client side use the server IP....
Check Firewalls... The address... Etc.

Comment: tried normal serversocket/socket method, it works. so ~~~ not sure server side: `set_time_limit(0);

$address='127.0.0.1';
$port=2012;

if (($serversock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) < 0) {
 echo "socket_create() fail:".socket_strerror($serversock)."<br>";
}
if (($ret = socket_bind($serversock, $address, $port)) < 0) {
 echo "socket_bind() fail:" . socket_strerror($ret) . "<br>";
}

if (($ret = socket_listen($serversock, 4)) < 0) {
 echo "socket_listen() fail:" . socket_strerror($ret) . "<br>";
}

$i = 0;
do {
 if (($msgsock = socket_accept($serversock)) < 0) { ...`

Comment: `client side: global $socket;
 set_time_limit(0);

 $address = "127.0.0.1";
 $service_port = 2012;

 $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
 if ($socket < 0) {
  return null;
 }

 $result = socket_connect($socket, $address, $service_port);`